# grep for a pattern where line does not start with another pattern

Tags: regex, grep

I am looking for instances of a class, say `Foo` except for the imports. That is, the matches should be as follows.

```
import com.acme.Foo; // Does not match
...
import com.acme.FooBar; // Does not match
...
  static Foo FOO = new Foo(); // matches
    ...
    Foo f = new Foo(); // matches
    FooBar.newFoo(); //  matches
```

I imagine this can be done with perl regexp with negative lookbehind? I do not know perl at so I am using `grep --perl-regexp` but not able to figure it out, mostly because I do not know perl regexps very well either. I could only come up with the following, neither of which works:

```
grep --perl-regexp -nH '(?<!import ).*Foo' t #matches all lines
grep --perl-regexp -nH '(?<!import .*)Foo' t #error: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length
```

I am open to using perl as well, given the exact command to use.

EDIT: As an aside, interestingly the perl answers are from users with appropriately cryptic and terse names -- hwnd and zx81 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **Negative Lookbehind**, use [Negative Lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookaround).

```
grep -P '^(?!.*import).*Foo' t
```

Or you can use a Perl one-liner.

```
perl -ne 'print if /^(?!.*import).*Foo/' t
```

Answer (score 1):

With your current input, you can use this:

```
grep -oP "^(?!.*import).*new ?\KFoo()" your path
```

to match just `Foo`.

If you want the whole line,

```
grep -P "^(?!.*import).*new ?Foo()" your path
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use two `grep`s:

```
grep "Foo" file(s) | grep -v "import"
```

Comment: That is what I was doing till I got this answer, but it skews the grep output since I am also using `--before-context`